# Wildfly 10 Custom Login Module not reaching the application after successful authentication

Tags: wildfly, jaas, wildfly-10

I have a struts 1.3 based J2EE application which is running on JBoss 4.4.2. I'm trying to migrate this to Wildfly 10. I'm able to deploy the application after some modification in WF. But the custom login module is not working. Below are the snippets:

1. Login Module:

   ```
   public class HRWorksLoginModule extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule {

       @Override
       public boolean login() throws LoginException {

           System.out.println("Inside login()");
           super.loginOk = false;
           String[] info = getUsernameAndPassword();
           System.out.println("info:");
           String name = info[0];
           System.out.println("name:" + name);
           String password = info[1];
           System.out.println("Inside login()");       
           if (name == null || password == null ) {
               throw new LoginException("Either Username or password is not available");
           }

           this.identity = new HRWorksPrincipal(name);

           if (!validatePassword(password)) {
               //validatePassword() -> implements application logic to validate the password
               throw new LoginException("Please enter the valid Password.");
           }
           sharedState.put("javax.security.auth.login.name", name);
           sharedState.put("javax.security.auth.login.password", credential);

           super.loginOk = true;
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       protected String getUsersPassword() throws LoginException {
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected boolean validatePassword(String inputPassword, String expectedPassword) {
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       protected Group[] getRoleSets() throws LoginException {
           System.out.println("Inside getRoleSets()");
           Group group = new SimpleGroup("Roles");
           Group callerPrincipal = new SimpleGroup("CallerPrincipal");
           callerPrincipal.addMember(identity);
           //Add more application roles to callerPrincipal
           return new Group[] {group, callerPrincipal};
       }

   }
   ```
2. standalone-full.xml:

   ```
   <security-domain name="hrworks" cache-type="default">
       <authentication>
           <login-module code="in.hinote.security.auth.HRWorksLoginModule" flag="required" module="in.hrworks.loginmodule">
               <module-option name="principalClass" value="in.hinote.security.HRWorksPrincipal"/>
               <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/Appscale"/>
           </login-module>
       </authentication>
       <authorization>
           <policy-module code="PermitAll" flag="required"/>
       </authorization>
   </security-domain>
   ```
3. web.xml:

   ```
   <security-constraint>
       <display-name>Login</display-name>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>Everything</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
           <http-method>GET</http-method>
           <http-method>POST</http-method>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
           <role-name>*</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
       <user-data-constraint>
           <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
       </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

   <security-role>
       <role-name>*</role-name>
   </security-role>

   <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <realm-name>hrworks</realm-name>
      <form-login-config>
           <form-login-page>/UserLogin.jsp</form-login-page>
           <form-error-page>/UserLogin.jsp</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
   ```
4. jboss-web.xml:

   ```
   <security-domain>hrworks</security-domain>
   ```

While debugging, I can see the login() returns without any error. But the request is not being redirected to the actual application url. Instead, its showing me the login page again. One thing I noticed is, its not calling the getRoleSets() method. I don't see any errors either in the logs. Its just showing me the login page again!

Am I making any mistakes here? Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem? 
I am very intresstet in your solution.

Comment: Yes, I was making a mistake. The commit() can not be left empty. Either we can remove it altogether or we'll have to implement it to call the getRollSet() and populate the members.